# If $3(u^2+v^2+w^2) = (u + v + w)^2$, then find the value of $u - 2v + w$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This might sound like I don't know anything for people who are advanced in this topic, but I'll ask it otherwise. I'll show the question, and the struggles I have.

> If $$3(u^2+v^2+w^2) = (u + v + w)^2$$
> find the value of $u - 2v + w$

I don't know too much about algebra (I'm a bit better in geometry), but I do know some simple stuff. 
First, I tried simplifying the right-hand side, it turned into:
$$(u + v + w)(u + v + w)$$
$$u^2 + v^2 + w^2 + 2uv + 2uw + 2vw$$
When it looked that complicated, I decided to try the left-hand side too, but it didn't help much:
$$3u^2+3v^2+3w^2 = u^2 + v^2 + w^2 + 2uv + 2uw + 2vw$$
simplifies to:
$$2u^2+2v^2+2w^2 = 2uv + 2uw + 2vw$$
This is where I'm officially stuck. With this equation, I realised that what I just wrote out might just say $1=1$.

Where did I go wrong? Or is there another crucial method that I skipped? Thanks :)

Comment: Certainly, if $u - 2v + w$ has a well-defined unique value, then it must be $0$, because if $(u, v, w) = (a, b, c)$ is one solution, then so is $(u, v, w) = (\lambda a, \lambda b, \lambda c)$ for all $\lambda$. But then $u - 2v + w$ would be come $a - 2b + c$ or $\lambda(a - 2b + c)$ respectively. The can only be equal for all $\lambda$ if $a - 2b + c = 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that $u,v,w\in\mathbb{R}$ and based on the relation you have obtained, it results that
\begin{align*}
2u^{2} + 2v^{2} + 2w^{2} = 2uv + 2uw + 2vw & \Longleftrightarrow (u - v)^{2} + (u - w)^{2} + (v - w)^{2} = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow u = v = w
\end{align*}

Hence $u - 2v + w = 0$.

Hopefully this helps!